Data Filtering Issues
I'm trying to filter in the body request in Copy Activity, but the issue is that it's not filtering the data. When I do this in Postman, the data gets filtered. Why is this so? Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?
 {
"Filters": [    
{
  "Route": "Production.HasBeenAddedBy",
  "Value": 5,
  "Operation": "NotEquals"
}
],
"Paging": {
"RecordsPerPage": 100,
"RequestedPage": 1
},
"ResponseBlocks": [

    "VacancyID",
"StartDate",
"EndDate",
"candidate"

]
}

I have tried the above filter query, but I am facing the same issue. You can try Dataflow as a workaround if none of your source and sink are not on-premises.
Give your source data as source in the dataflow. In between the source and sink, you can use transformations like select and filter to get the required data from source.

Use the select transformation to select your inner objects as columns. Then, use filter transformation to filter out the required data from the columns. You can make use of Dataflow expressions to build the correct expression as per your input data.
You can use REST API dataset as the sink of the Dataflow.

Set the pagination here and call the dataflow from the pipeline using dataflow activity.

cant we do filter in Activty rather then in data flow if we can can you tell me how

I have tried the same but it's not giving the required result for me that's why I have provided a workaround. If you want to do it only in the ADF pipeline instead of dataflow, then I think you need to use loop approach for each page. Use lookup for your source and get the data and use filter activity to filter out the data. After filtering, use a web activity to post this filtered data to your API. You need to do this for every page in the loop.
